# passing a HashMap from one activity to another, android

Tags: android

I am writing an android application to display nearby locations. I stored then in a hashmap list like this

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
```

in the first activity I displayed places on a map, and I want to pass them to another activity to list then in a listView.

in the first activity I have a button to direct me to the list activity like this:

```
public void list_airports(View v)
        {
            Intent intent;
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.list_items:
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), List_airports.class);
                intent.putExtra("places",places);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            }
            }
```

in the next activity I did this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_airports);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String[] places=extras.getStringArray(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

but the method putExtra doesn't accept `List<HashMap<String, String>>`

Comment: You are correct, the method putExtra doesn't accept List<HashMap<String,String>>... so whats the question?

Comment: @Scott the question is: is there a way to pass 'List<HashMap<String, String>>'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use intent.putExtra(String, Serializable) - see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29.
i.e.

```
intent.putExtra("placesHashMap", places)
```

In the receiving activity use

```
HashMap<String, String> places = (HashMap<String, String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("placesHashMap");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `putExtra(String, Serializable)` to pass it in Intent and `getSerializableExtra(String)` method to retrieve it.

Also, use `ArrayList` instead of `List`

Answer (score 0):

What is [**Serializable**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)

Serializable take screenshot of your current class

**1. Passes intent from context class to new class**

> ```
> HashMap<String, String> hashMap= adapter.getItem(position);
> Intent intent = new Intent(OneActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
> intent.putExtra("key", value);
> startActivity(intent);
> ```

**2.Retrive hash map to other class**

```
Bundle b=getIntent.getExtra();
 if(b!=null)
   {
     yourhasmaplist=b.getSerializableExtra("key"); 
   }
```